# Ignore Google Smart Home intents during a dialogflow agent conversation?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant

I've built an agent in Dialogflow and I've deployed a test version to Google Home. When I'm talking to my agent on the Google Home, if I ask it "what's the news today" or any sort of intent that isn't included in my agent but can be asked outside of my Test App, then the Google Assistant will exit my Test App and respond with a normal Google Home response.

How do I get my agent to ignore all the default Google Home intents when I'm talking to my agent?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify these points? 1)Does your agent have similar intents(training phrases) that you're providing in Google Assistant? 2)While integrating Google Assistant did you configure explicit invocation of intent as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/data/google-assistant-legacy.pdf)?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan 1) No I don't have any similar intents. I would like questions like "What's the weather like today" do be caught in the fallback intent. However, Google Home simply exits the test app and answers normally. 2) Yes I have configured explicit invocation.

Comment: Did you try handling the [unrecognized action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/dialogflow/define-actions#handling_an_unrecognized_action) using fallback as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/dialogflow/fulfillment#no-match_reprompting)?

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489240/fallback-intent-with-sys-any

Comment: Hi @JoshuaGao, is your issue resolved? Did the above comments help in resolving your issue?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Yes my issue is resolved through the similar question provided by Nick Felker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fallback intent with sys any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489240/fallback-intent-with-sys-any)